# Other than /etc/rc.conf what other config files control system services at boot time?

Tags: freebsd, startup

I am still very new to FreeBSD, from what I have learned in manuals, `/etc/rc.conf` controls system services at boot time.

There is no mention of sendmail and syslogd in `/etc/rc.conf`, so how come they are started automatically? Is there another configuration file for system services at boot time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `/etc/defaults/rc.conf`. The defaults there are the basis and `/etc/rc.conf` contains only changes that overwrite the defaults.

If you want very verbose information you can also get debug messages from the rc scripts with `rc_debug="YES"`.

Comment: awesome answer, thanks a lot, that's exactly where sendmail and syslog started

Answer (score 0):

You could be running systemd, try running:

```
systemctl list-unit-files
```

Comment: There does not seem to be systemd. This is a fresh installation of freebsd 9.1 from dvd image.

Answer (score 0):

FreeBSD has a wonderful handbook.

http://www.freebsd.org/doc/en/books/handbook/boot.html